# How to initialize a pointer appropriately to avoid segmentation fault in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have started learning c++ (coming from java background) and barely reached pointers and got stuck. When I debug this program it says, program received segmentation fault (SIGSEGV signal) at line

*previous = head;

in the following code.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 
 struct Node
 {
    int data;
    Node *link;
 };
 
 int main()
 {
 
    cout << "Starting main program \n";
    Node head;
    head.data = 0;
    head.link = NULL;
    
    cout << "After declaring head and initializing values \n";
    
    //Declaring a pointer variable which points to an entity of type struct.
    Node *previous;
    *previous=head;
    
    cout << "After declaring previous pointer \n";
    
    bool done = false;
    int i = 1;

    cout << "First while loop\n";   
    while(!done)
    {
        cout << i << ": Iteration";
        Node temp;
        temp.data=i;
        temp.link=NULL;
        if(i > 2)
        {
            done = true;
            continue;
        }
        *previous->link=temp;
        ++i;
        *previous = temp;   
    }
    
    done = false;
    
    cout << "Declaring temp pointer before printing \n";
    Node *temp;
    *temp = head;
    
    cout << "Second while loop\n";  
    while (!done)
    {
        cout << i << ": Iteration";
        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            done = true;
            continue;
        }
        cout << temp->data << "->";
        *temp = *temp->link;
    }
    cout << "NULL";
 }
```

Why is the pointer initialization incorrect ?

Comment: Try just `previous=head;` instead of `*previous=head;` Also `temp=head;` instead of `*temp=head;`

Comment: yes as @NathanMills said . Also Try  *previous=&head; instead of  *previous=head.

Comment: @NathanMills - It gives a compilation error, "cannot convert node to node * in assignment"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem:

```
Node *previous;
*previous=head;
```

First line declares that previous will hold the address of a Node.  It is not initialized, so whatever value happens to be on the stack will be picked up as the bit pattern it holds.

Unfortunately, the 2nd line then dereferences the pointer (which points to garbage) and attempts to copy head into random memory (hence your crash).

In this case you probably want previous to point to head, which is taking head's address and assigning it:

```
Node* previous = &head;  // initialize at the point of declaration
```

However, you must also be very wary of pointers to variables declared on the stack, because the addresses will soon become invalid when the function returns or the scope exits.
(Usually data structures with pointers are using values allocated on the heap, so the objects outlive the function that declares them.)

Which brings us to the second problem:

```
while(!done)
{
    cout << i << ": Iteration";
    Node temp;
```

Already there's a problem.  `temp` is declared inside the loop on the stack.  Each loop iteration, the variable will automatically be destroyed.  Therefore it cannot participate in your linked list without corrupting it.

You want your list nodes to be created with `new`, and when you update previous's next pointer, you want to assign an address TO it, not copy an object THROUGH it.

Something like this:

```
while(!done)
{
    cout << i << ": Iteration";
    Node * temp = new Node();
    temp->data = i;
    temp->link = nullptr;  // better than NULL
    if(i > 2)
    {
        break;
    }
    previous->link = temp;
    ++i;
    previous = temp;   
}
```

The `head` object should probably also be heap allocated.  Of course, now you have to deal with cleaning up the memory by calling delete on all the nodes.

Comment: Please give me some time to try this solution, will get back. I do not have the knowledge as to when to use new keyword. In java without a new keyword, we cant create an object but an object is of a class, here in this example i refrained from using class and instead used struct.

Comment: In c++, a class and struct are the nearly identical constructs, differing only in default access of members and bases.  But we _think_ of class as object and struct as just a blob of data, but that's just for human perspectives.

Answer (score 1):

There were some bugs in the code but major ones were :-

1. you were not allocating memory for the new nodes that you were adding during runtime
2. you were creating instances of structure but instead you were required to create an pointer pointing to the structure ( instances will be created during runtime ( using `new` operator )

I have added the comments to the code explaining what exactly are the changes that I have done.

Here is the fix :-

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 
 struct Node
 {
    int data;
    Node *link;
 };
 
 int main()
 {
 
    cout << "Starting main program \n";
    // Allocating memory for the new instance of Node and making "head" pointing to it
    Node *head = new Node;
    head->data = 0;
    head->link = NULL;
    
    cout << "After declaring head and initializing values \n";
    
    //Declaring a pointer variable which points to an entity of type struct.
    Node *previous;
    // As head and previous both are pointers thus can be assigned as it is
    previous = head;
    
    cout << "After declaring previous pointer \n";
    
    bool done = false;
    int i = 1;

    cout << "First while loop\n";   
    while(!done)
    {
        cout << i << ": Iteration";
        
        // Allocating memory for the new instance of Node and making temp pointing to it
        Node *temp = new Node;  
        
        // As temp is a pointer thus using member access ("- >") operator to access the members
        temp->data=i;
        temp->link=NULL;
        
        if(i > 2)
        {
            done = true;
            continue;
        }
        
        previous->link = temp;
        ++i;
        previous = temp;
        
    }
    
    done = false;
    
    cout << "Declaring temp pointer before printing \n";
    Node *temp;
    temp = head;
    
    cout << "Second while loop\n";  
    while (!done)
    {
        cout << i << ": Iteration";
        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            done = true;
            continue;
        }
        cout << temp->data << "->";
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    cout << "NULL";
 }
```

Comment: @Arsenic- Let me try and get back. I am confused about the usage of new as I am not using the concept of class, its just struct. In java there are no structs and an object cannot be created without new, however we can let struct possess values without new keyword.